# TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion

I have a problem with this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('sheet_path', 'sheet_name', dtype={'col1':str})
```

when I try to execute the code I receive an error:
TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

I try with pandas 1.5.3, 1.4.2, 1.5.2 version in two kind of environment:

- conda environment: one environment with pandas installed with pip and one environment with pandas with conda
- virtualenv with pip installation of pandas

I expect that this keyword, as explained in the documentation, permit to define the datatype of a column that now is read as numeric integer but I need to read it as string.